# Convert Simple json Array to string Array In C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a string contain a json array.

The array look like this:

```
[item1, item2, item3]
```

I need a c# function to convert this json to `string[]`

I couldn't find any example/tutorial for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your string variable is the string representation of an array like

```
"['item1', 'item2', 'item3']"
```

Then you can deserialize it using one of the serializers. Here is one example using [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
var a = "['item1', 'item2', 'item3']";
string[] resultArray = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(a);
```

The string `[item1, item2, item3]` does not look like the stringified version of an array and cannot be easily converted to an array like we did above, as it is.

If your string variable value is something like `item1, item2, item3`, you can call `string.Split` method which will give you an array.

```
var a = "item1, item2, item3";
string[] resultArray = a.Split(',');
```